# How to know the lane position on road?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gps

I'm using Python to map match a given trajectory to a real lane of a road. However, the match is done in a random lane instead of the rightest lane. How can I choose to move the coordinates to the same position (distance) but in the rightest lane? The following code shows the roads of the given area and, among other attributes, the number of lanes.

```
north1, east1 = np.max(np.array([*points1]), 0)
south1, west1 = np.min(np.array([*points1]), 0)
G1 = graph.graph_from_bbox(*distance.enlarge_bbox(north1, south1, west1, east1, 500), simplify=True, network_type='drive')

edges1 = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True)
```

How can I know the number of lane in which I'm located?

Comment: What do you mean by "the rightest lane"?  Do you mean "the actual lane / correct lane" (i.e. the lane the vehicle actually occupied) or do you mean "the right-most lane" (i.e. the lane you would expect a slow vehicle to be travelling in, in USA or Europe)?   And how are you getting the actual trajectory?  If GNSS, how accurate is that?

Comment: About the rightest lane is the-right-most-lane. These coordinates are from Europe (Spain), the actual trajectory was simulated with SUMO, I don't know the GNSS accuracy.

Comment: In California highways, this is generally called Lane 1. Caltrans, at least when I was there, puts their road lines in Lane 1 and measures distances from this lane. This is because there is always a Lane 1 in each direction, even on a 2-lane highway. So, do you have a good roadway dataset?